# Exceeded maximum execution time google script while extract email addresses from my Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've a google sheet script that can extract emails from gmail labels it work very well on small number of emails but if the emails to in large number it gives me time out error "Exceeded maximum execution time" Is there anyone that can help me out from this problem? following i'm attaching the code that is woking fine with small number of emails but not on large number of emails.
I copy this script form [here](https://helgeklein.com/blog/extracting-all-email-addresses-from-a-gmail-label/).

```
function GetAddresses ()
{
  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  

  // Label to search
  var userInputSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  
  var labelName = userInputSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  
  // Create / empty the target sheet
  var sheetName = "Label: " + labelName;
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName (sheetName) || ss.insertSheet (sheetName, ss.getSheets().length);
  sheet.clear();
  
  // Get all messages in a nested array (threads -> messages)
  var addressesOnly = [];
  var messageData = [];

  var startIndex = 0;
  var pageSize = 100;
  while (1)
  {
    // Search in pages of 100
    var threads = GmailApp.search ("label:" + labelName, startIndex, pageSize);
    if (threads.length == 0)
      break;
    else
      startIndex += pageSize;
       
    // Get all messages for the current batch of threads
    var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads (threads);
    
    // Loop over all messages
    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length ; i++)
    {
      // Loop over all messages in this thread
      for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++)
      {
        var mailFrom = messages[i][j].getFrom ();
        var mailDate = messages[i][j].getDate ();
        
        // mailFrom format may be either one of these:
        // name@domain.com
        // any text <name@domain.com>
        // "any text" <name@domain.com>
        
        var name = "";
        var email = "";
        var matches = mailFrom.match (/\s*"?([^"]*)"?\s+<(.+)>/);
        if (matches)
        {
          name = matches[1];
          email = matches[2];
        }
        else
        {
          email = mailFrom;
        }
        // Check if (and where) we have this already
        var index = addressesOnly.indexOf (mailFrom);
        if (index > -1)
        {
          // We already have this address -> remove it (so that the result is ordered by data from new to old)
          addressesOnly.splice(index, 1);
          messageData.splice(index, 1);
        }
        
        // Add the data
        addressesOnly.push (mailFrom);
        messageData.push ([name, email, mailDate]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Add data to corresponding sheet
  sheet.getRange (1, 1, messageData.length, 3).setValues (messageData);
}


//
// Adds a menu to easily call the script
//
function onOpen ()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  
  var menu = [ 
    {name: "Extract email addresses",functionName: "GetAddresses"}
  ];  
  
  sheet.addMenu ("Start Extracting", menu);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are receiving this error message as your code is exceeding the maximum execution time for `Apps Script`. Currently the limit is of 6 minutes. You can verify this information in the [`Current limitations`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations).

You will notice that this is the information displayed for the runtime quota:

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. But is there any solution that we can save progress before the time limit is reached and run the script again where form its stops?

Comment: Usually with these type of issues you need to follow [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) so your code performs better.